# How to connect with server using Secure WebSocket in Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, websocket

> I am creating Qt application that should be able to connect with
>   server using secure connection (i.e. wss://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080),
>   Application is working fine with none-secure connection  (i.e.
>   ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443).

Protocol i am using is WebSocket. I have used  library for connection.

> Qt Creator 3.4.2 (opensource) Based on Qt 5.5.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)

**QsslSocket::supportsSsl()** was returning **false**, then find out that i was missing openssl library files ( **libeay32.dll , ssleay32.dll** ) then i put these file in the path of my application and run code again now QSslSocket::supportsSsl() is returning **true**. but when i try to connect websocket it is showing flollowing errors.

connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList)), SLOT(onSslErrors(QList)), Qt::DirectConnection);

> onSslErrors : unknown error onError : "The host name did not match any
>   of the valid hosts for this certificate"  Error:
>   QAbstractSocket::SocketError(13)

**code snippet from client side(Qt)**

```
void onConnectToServer()
{
   qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>();
    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSocket::SocketState>();
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), SLOT(onSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(connected()), SLOT(onConnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(binaryMessageReceived(QByteArray)), SLOT(onBinaryMessage(QByteArray)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(textMessageReceived(QString)), SLOT(onTextMessage(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), SLOT(onDisconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(&wsocket, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), SLOT(onStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), Qt::DirectConnection);

    QUrl serverURL;
    QWebSocket wsocket;

     // some code for here and setting **serverURL**

    wsocket.setPauseMode(QAbstractSocket::PauseNever);
    wsocket.open(serverURL);

}

void onSslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{
    qDebug() << wsocket.errorString();
}

void onError(const QAbstractSocket::SocketError &socketError)
{
    qDebug() << wsocket.errorString() << " Error:" << socketError;
}

void onConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Successfully Connected with " << serverURL;
}

void onDisconnected()
{
    qDebug() << wsocket.errorString() << " CloseCode is >>> " << wsocket.closeCode();
}

void onStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState socketState)
{
    qDebug() << "StateChanged : " << socketState;
}
```

how to resolve this any one have idea how to connect secure web socket. i did check [SSL Echo Client Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-sslechoclient-example.html) but it seems like server side also should be Qt WebSocket.

> Q1) How to make secure connection using Qt from client side?
>
> NOTE: server side is configured for secure connection already.
>
> Q2) Server side is not Qt Code and client side is Qt. does it in
>   secure web socket connection? (i.e. server Socket and client Socket are independent of programming Language for connection or not?)
>
> NOTE: i'm able to connect with same server using none secure
>   connection.

Comment: It looks like your certificate isn't made for this server. How did you create it?

Comment: i created it with openssl , self signed certificate for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found solution after all,

Before I open connection to the remote server using this line,

> wsocket.open(serverURL);

I added QSslConfiguration and ignore ssl Error for self signed certificate for development , of course i will correc that in Production.

```
QSslConfiguration sslConfiguration = wsocket.sslConfiguration();
sslConfiguration.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyPeer);
wsocket.setSslConfiguration(sslConfiguration);
wsocket.ignoreSslErrors();
```